# Conditional data insertion in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have an empty `LIST`, where I want to insert some `CONTACT` data. I have write the following query:

```
MERGE (u:CONTACT { id: 'random-id-01', email: 'some01@email.com', name: 'some-name-01', info: 'some-info-01 } )

  WITH u as u

  MATCH (pl:LIST { id: {listId} } ) 
     MERGE (pl)-[plcn:LIST_CONTACTS]->(u)

  RETURN u
```

But I also have to check duplicate email. So I have write the following query:

```
MATCH (pl:LIST)-[plcn:LIST_CONTACTS]->(ux:CONTACT)
    WHERE ux.email <> 'some01@email.com'

MERGE (u:CONTACT { id: 'random-id-01', email: 'some01@email.com', name: 'some-name-01', info: 'some-info-01 } )

  WITH u as u

  MATCH (pl:LIST { id: {listId} } ) 
     MERGE (pl)-[plcn:LIST_CONTACTS]->(u)

  RETURN u
```

This query only works when some `CONTACT` data are already exist. But when   an empty `LIST` is created and then want to insert `CONTACT` data into that newly created `LIST`, then it is not working.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want every `CONTACT` node to have a unique email address?

Answer (score 1):

If you want email to be unique among :CONTACT nodes, then create a unique constraint on :CONTACT(email), that will ensure an error is thrown when an insert attempt violates the uniqueness constraint.

I'm not quite understanding your intent with the MATCH of all contacts with a different email than the one you want to insert. Can you clarify what you're attempting?